# Show that $\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha = \sin4\alpha\cos\alpha - \cos4\alpha\sin\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha = \sin4\alpha\cos\alpha - \cos4\alpha\sin\alpha$

I know that $\sin2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$

so
$$\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha$$
and $\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha$ can be expressed in three ways: 
$$(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\sin\alpha =\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha-\sin^3\alpha$$
$$(2\cos^2\alpha -1)\sin\alpha = 2\cos^2\alpha\sin\alpha - \sin\alpha$$
$$(1-2\sin^2\alpha)\sin\alpha = \sin\alpha - 2\sin^3\alpha$$
I tried adding these, but nothing came close to the required answer.
So then I tried calculating $\sin4\alpha$ (from the required answer):
$$\sin4\alpha=2\sin(2\alpha)\cdot\cos(2\alpha)$$
$$\sin4\alpha=2\cdot2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)$$
$$\sin4\alpha=4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)$$
so $$\sin4\alpha\cos\alpha= 4\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)$$
Still looking at the answer, I calculated $\cos4\alpha$
$$\cos4\alpha = 1- \sin^2(2\alpha)$$
If $$\sin2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$
then $$\sin^22\alpha= (2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)^2$$
and $$\cos4\alpha = 1 - 4\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha$$
and $$\cos4\alpha\sin\alpha=\sin\alpha-4\sin^3\alpha\cos^2\alpha$$ 
I have tried subtracting my values for $\sin4\alpha\cos\alpha$ and  $\cos4\alpha\sin\alpha$, but I have not come close to a solution.

Comment: the formulas for cos4α and sin4α you are trying to use are not correct. and answers are pretty comprehensive. I just wanted to point out that cos4α is not equal to cos2α*cos2α.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use  $$\sin(A+B) = \sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B $$on LHS and 
$$\sin(A-B) =\sin A\cos B - \cos A\sin B$$ on RHS

so $$\sin(3\alpha) = \sin(3\alpha)$$

Comment: Hi @yanbo, may I know why you removed kahan academy links from my answer ?

Comment: I didn't realise I did that. Terribly sorry. Gave you a +1 though, hope that makes it up.

Comment: Ya Ya no problem .I added the links so that he can know the proof also .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need help to understand it and I know this is probably a dumb follow up question, so sorry.   Using $\sin(A+B) = \sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B $  on the LHS gives $\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha$ using the terms in my question. What I don't get is where this gives just $\sin3\alpha$ on the LHS. Isn't there still a $\cos\alpha$ term?

Comment: A = $2\alpha$ and  B= $\alpha$ so A+B = $3\alpha$

Comment: You just apply the identity separately on RHS and LHS .

Comment: In RHS A -> $4\alpha$ and B -> $\alpha$ so A-B = $4\alpha - \alpha $ = $3\alpha$

Answer (score 4):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be.  One is $\sin{(2 \alpha + \alpha)}$.  The other is $\sin{(4 \alpha-\alpha)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Just remember that $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta + \cos \alpha \sin \beta$ and $\sin (\alpha - \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta - \cos \alpha \sin \beta$ and apply the r.h.s. of each of these equalities to your example.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Take the real part of this complex number

$$-ie^{i\alpha}e^{2i\alpha}=-ie^{-i\alpha}e^{4i\alpha}$$